# R: Using "otherwise" in RECODE function

Tags: r, recode, r-car

I would like to recode numeric values to ordinal variable using 'car' library.

However, it seems that I'm unable to use "otherwise" in my recode function.

Can I know how to fix the code if I want to code any other values that are not within (0.0 to 9.0) to 999 in this case?

Thank you.

Here's my code:

```
newvar <- apply(abc, 2, function(x) {x <- 
    recode(x,         
         "0.0:1.5=1;
          1.6:1.7=2;
          1.8:1.9=3;
          2.0:2.4=4;
          2.5:2.9=5;
          3.0:3.4=6;
          3.5:3.9=7;
          4.0:4.4=8;
          4.5:9.0=9;
          otherwise =999"); x})

message: Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'otherwise' not found
```

Would like to have new variable (def) as below:

```
abc     def
0.5     1
3.5     7
11.5    999
5.8     9
```

Comment: What is `abc` ?

Comment: @akrun is my variable name for numeric values

Comment: It would be better to show a reproducible example

Comment: Isn't it `else=` ? - according to `?car::recode` it is anyway.